# how to move in bytes in an unsigned char in c

Tags: c, byte, unsigned-char

let's say that i have an unsigned char declared as follow :

```
unsigned char Data[DATA_BLOCK_SIZE] = {0};
```

What is the meaning of expression `Data+1`?

Comment: that means that `Data` now points to the second element in the array. `Data` is assigned the address of the first element in the array, so `Data+1` is that address + 1 (aka the address of the next element in row)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an `unsigned char`, but an `unsigned char []`. It means you have an array of `unsigned char`. When you do arithmetic operations upon `Data`, you move in this array.

When you do Data + 1, it's like doing one of the following

```
&Data[1]
(&Data[0]) + 1
```

It is called **pointer arithmetic**. `Data` is not a pointer (you can not assign an address to it) but when you make `Data + 1`, an implicit cast is done and `Data` equals its first block address (`&Data[0]`).

Answer (score 2):

`Data` points to `Data[0]`, `Data + 1` will point to `Data[1]`.

Comment: Arrays are _not_ pointers... don't confuse the two, because it'll come back to bite you!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I removed word pointer. But isn't `Data` is pointer to `Data[0]`? I am not saying array and pointer are same. But internally name of array acts as pointer?

Comment: No, an array can be used as a pointer, but internally there is quite a difference. For example: `sizeof(Data)` will yield the array length. A pointer will always be size 4 on 32 bit, 8 on 64 bit... a pointer is a different type all together: an array _"knows"_ its size and type, a pointer doesn't. It can't, it shouldn't either.

Comment: I've added a link to a page that explains the differences between arrays and pointers quite clearly. Read that, if you haven't already

Answer (score 1):

`Data+1` means the address of the second element in array `Data`; if you want to access the second element itself, you could use `Data[1]` or `*(Data+1)`, they are the same in C.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers are *not* the same thing, but they behave in a similar fashion, like here. `Data` holds the memory address of the fist element in the array. Like a pointer holds the memory address of something.
Add 1 to that address, and you get the address of the second item in the array (ie `Data[1]`, only `Data[1]` refers to the actual *value*, `Data+1` resolves to the memory address)

You see this syntax pretty often, mainly in loops because it doesn't require one to use a temp variable like `int i` or `size_t len` or something.

In your case, an illustration to erase all doubt:

```
Data = 0x01 //value of Data
//layout in memory
 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 
| \0 | \0 | \0 | \0 | \0 |
```

Now if you write: `Data[0]`, it's the same as writing `*(data+0)` with a pointer: it dereferences it, thus fetching the value stored in memory
Writing `Data+1`, then is the same as incrementing a pointer by 1:

```
Data+1 == 0x02 != Data[1]
//because:
Data[1] == *(Data+1);
```

So in a loop, counting the number of, say `'a'`'s in a string like "flabbergast", one could write:

```
char word[] = "flabbergast";
int a_count = 0;
do
{
    if (*word == 'a') ++a_count;
    ++word;
} while (*word != '\0');
```

Effectively using `word` as an array.

***Note that arrays and pointers are NOT the same thing***
[Read this for details](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html)